# ¿Cómo evitar que los usuarios accedan a otros módulos mediante la modificación de URL?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, en el cual hay asignados roles para cada tipo de usuario según su nivel de privilegios en el sistema, por lo tanto dependiendo del rol que tenga, tiene acceso a ciertas partes del sistema.

Mi problema es que si un usuario por ejemplo de Recursos Humanos coloca en la URL el link para acceder al modulo de Operaciones, tiene completo acceso a este.

Por lo tanto lo que quiero lograr es evitar que los usuarios tengan acceso a otros módulos mediante la modificación de la URL.

El proyecto lo estoy elaborando con php, CodeIgniter3 y MySQL.

Tengo definidos modelos para la validación y verificación mediante consultas a la base de datos para obtener los datos del usuario y que rol tiene y así mismo mostrar solo los módulos que tiene acceso en el menú el cual si muestra a que módulos tiene acceso en el menú.

#Clase para mostrar módulos al cual tiene acceso

```
 class Menu_Model extends CI_Model {

      function __construct()
      {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->load->database();
      }
      
      public function getMenuByLevelAndUser($level, $userId){
          $sql = "SELECT m.* FROM tblmenu m
                inner join tblrole_menu rm on rm.menuId = m.menuId
                inner join tbluser u on u.roleId = rm.roleId
                where u.userId = ? and m.level= ? order by orderIdx";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($userId,$level));
          $res = $query->result();
          return $res;
      }

      public function getMenuByLevel($level){
          $sql = "Select * from tblmenu where level = ? order by 'order'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($level));
          $res = $query->result();
          return $res;
      }

      public function getParentMenus(){
          $sql = "SELECT m.level, m.menuId, case when m.level = 1 then
                        m.label
                    else
                        case when m.level = 2 then
                            CONCAT(mp.label, '/', m.label)
                        else
                            CONCAT(mp2.label, '/' ,mp.label, '/', m.label)
                        end
                    end as label
                    FROM tblmenu m
                    left join tblmenu mp on mp.menuId = m.parentMenuId
                    left join tblmenu mp2 on mp2.menuId = mp.parentMenuId
                    where m.url = ''
                    order by m.level";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);
          $res = $query->result();
          return $res;
      }

      public function getChildMenus($parentMenuId){
          $sql = "Select * from tblmenu where parentMenuId = ? order by 'order'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($parentMenuId));
          $res = $query->result();
          return $res;
      }

      public function getChildMenusByUser($parentMenuId,$userId){
          $sql = "SELECT m.* FROM tblmenu m
                inner join tblrole_menu rm on rm.menuId = m.menuId
                inner join tbluser u on u.roleId = rm.roleId
                where u.userId = ? and m.parentMenuId= ? order by 'order'";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($userId,$parentMenuId));
          $res = $query->result();
          return $res;
      }

      public function insertMenu($data){
          $this->db->insert('tblMenu', $data);
          return $this->db->insert_id();
      }

      public function updateMenu($menuId, $level, $parentMenuId, $order){
          $this->db->set('level', $level);
          $this->db->set('parentMenuId', $parentMenuId);
          $this->db->set('orderIdx', $order);
          $this->db->where('menuId', $menuId);
          $this->db->update('tblmenu');
          return true;
      }

      public function updateMenuOrder($menuId, $order){
          $this->db->set('orderIdx', $order);
          $this->db->where('menuId', $menuId);
          $this->db->update('tblmenu');
          return true;
      }

  }
```

En cada modulo de la carpeta controllers  tengo un constructor que me checa que el usuario este autenticado como es lo siguiente:

```
 function __construct()
{
    $this->authorization->checkAuth();
    $this->userId = $this->authorization->getUserIdFromToken(); 
    // Construct the parent class
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Remisiones_Model',"mdl_rem");
$this->load->model('Process_Model', 'mdl_proc');
    
}
```

Comment: Hay varias alternativas, podrias utilizar un [Hook](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html) en el **post_controller_constructor** o **post_controller** para verificar el tipo de rol y redirigir a una pagina de inicio según el nombre del controlador o nombre de función

Comment: Aparte de verificar que el usuario tiene sesión iniciada, también debes revisar el rol, si no corresponde al del módulo actual, muestra mensaje de error o redirige a la página adecuada.